# text is not displaying properly in HTML

Tags: html, css

My "please wait" text is breaking from "please". I want to display it as a full sentence. I tried a lot but my all try is failed. How can I resolve this issue?

```css
.loading {
  width: 100PX;
  height: 100PX;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: show;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.loading:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.l_main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
@-webkit-keyframes hei {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
    width: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0%;
    width: 0%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rot {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
.l_main {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: rot 3s linear infinite;
}
.l_main .quater {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.l_main .circle {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #3d9bb5;
  -webkit-animation: hei 3s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 5;
}
.l_main .quater {
  z-index: 10;
}
.quater span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  clear: both;
  background-color: white;
}
.quater .top {
  float: right;
}
.quater .bottom {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <h3 style="color:#000">Please wait...</h3>
  <div class="l_main">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="quater">
      <span class="top"></span>
      <span class="bottom"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want the text to be displayed. Please explain.

Comment: right now it displaying like please and then breaking and then wait. I want to display full text without breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `white-space: nowrap;` to `h3` to fix your problem

```css
.loading {
  width: 100PX;
  height: 100PX;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: show;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.loading:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.loading h3 {
   white-space: nowrap;
 }
.l_main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
@-webkit-keyframes hei {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
    width: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0%;
    width: 0%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rot {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
.l_main {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: rot 3s linear infinite;
}
.l_main .quater {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.l_main .circle {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #3d9bb5;
  -webkit-animation: hei 3s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 5;
}
.l_main .quater {
  z-index: 10;
}
.quater span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  clear: both;
  background-color: white;
}
.quater .top {
  float: right;
}
.quater .bottom {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <h3 style="color:#000">Please wait...</h3>
  <div class="l_main">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="quater">
      <span class="top"></span>
      <span class="bottom"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `h3` wider

```css
h3 {
  width: 150px;
}
.loading {
  width: 100PX;
  height: 100PX;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: show;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.loading:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.l_main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
@-webkit-keyframes hei {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
    width: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0%;
    width: 0%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rot {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
.l_main {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: rot 3s linear infinite;
}
.l_main .quater {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.l_main .circle {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #3d9bb5;
  -webkit-animation: hei 3s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 5;
}
.l_main .quater {
  z-index: 10;
}
.quater span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  clear: both;
  background-color: white;
}
.quater .top {
  float: right;
}
.quater .bottom {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <h3 style="color:#000">Please wait...</h3>
  <div class="l_main">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="quater">
      <span class="top"></span>
      <span class="bottom"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in below and your code will work perfectly :

```
.loading {
    width: 103px;
    height: 101px;
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    overflow: show;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to the width of .loading

```
.loading {
  width: 120PX;
....
}
```

```css
.loading {
  width: 120PX;
  height: 100PX;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: show;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.loading:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.l_main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
@-webkit-keyframes hei {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
    width: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0%;
    width: 0%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rot {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
.l_main {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: rot 3s linear infinite;
}
.l_main .quater {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.l_main .circle {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #3d9bb5;
  -webkit-animation: hei 3s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 5;
}
.l_main .quater {
  z-index: 10;
}
.quater span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  clear: both;
  background-color: white;
}
.quater .top {
  float: right;
}
.quater .bottom {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <h3 style="color:#000">Please wait...</h3>
  <div class="l_main">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="quater">
      <span class="top"></span>
      <span class="bottom"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your sentence is breaking is simply because there is not enough space. You have a set width on `.loading`, namely `.loading {width: 100px}`, either make this a larger width or remove the width declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
.loading:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

Change the background color to  `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);`

On IE the text is showing but the background is too dark with black text.